# python xml.sax no parser found py2exe

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to get my game to run. the code requires xml.sax. I import it with py2exe and it still doesn't want to work. I've tried for days and days and I cannot get it to work. Before I compile it to a .exe it works but whenever I compile it to a exe it doesn't work.

Running:

[-] Python 2.7.9 32-bit

[-] py2exe 0.6.9 32-bit

The error is: `SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found`

Here is my game code:

```
import xml.sax

class DNAError(Exception): pass
class DNAParseError(DNAError): pass

elementRegistry = {}
def registerElement(element):
  elementRegistry[element.TAG] = element

class DNASaxHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
def __init__(self):
    xml.sax.ContentHandler.__init__(self)

    self.stack = []
    self.root = None

def startElement(self, tag, attrs):
    if self.stack:
        parent = self.stack[-1]
        parentTag = parent.TAG
    else:
        parent = None
        parentTag = None

    element = elementRegistry.get(tag)
    if not element:
        raise DNAParseError('Unknown element type: ' + tag)

    if parentTag not in element.PARENTS:
        raise DNAParseError('Cannot put %s below %s element' % (tag, parentTag))

    element = element(**attrs)
    self.stack.append(element)
    element.reparentTo(parent)

    if not self.root:
        self.root = element

def endElement(self, tag):
    self.stack.pop(-1)

def characters(self, chars):
    if not self.stack:
        return

    self.stack[-1].handleText(chars)

def parse(stream):
handler = DNASaxHandler()
xml.sax.parse(stream, handler)
return handler.root
```

Here is my compile script for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
options={"py2exe": {"includes": [ "xml.sax.drivers.*", "xml.sax.drivers2.*", "xml.sax" ] }},
zipfile = None,
windows = ['relived.py']
)
```

Comment: omg please! I've had this error for days and days!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your setup.py py2exe command line:

```
--packages xml.sax.drivers,xml.sax.drivers2
```

[from this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyXML)

Comment: SAXReaderNotAvailable: No parsers found